# We can notice.... vs We can see

Tags: modal-verbs

It is quite possible to say "We can see from the text that ...." But,  is it possible to say "We can notice from the text ..." ? The latter just doesn't sound correct to me, and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I think _notice **in** the text_ sounds a little more natural than _notice **from** the text_, but, without a complete sentence to analyze, it's hard to say much more than that.

Answer (score 2):

"We can see from the text" has a connotation that we *understand* something from this text, we gain some insight from the text.

"Noticing" implies simply becoming aware of some superficial fact, without understanding an underlying reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

"We can notice" isn't as common as "We can see" but it's possible.  Its meaning is slightly different, and it's always a transitive verb, where "see" doesn't have to be.  You could think of it as

> We can take note of such-and-so from [*or* in] the text.

Here's the relevant [Random House definition](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/notice):

> to become aware of or pay attention to; take notice of; observe.